# How do I place a widget for Stack Overflow on my WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, widget

I want a Stack Overflow widget on my WordPress site.

How can I do that?

Comment: a widget of stackoverflow .. any idea with this??

Comment: You want a widget of the *entire* StackOverflow site? I'm sure that's not what you mean; please give more details. You may also want to ask at SO's sister site about WordPress: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: i mean to say that in my wordpress site , i want a widget of stackoverflow i the right column which can link to my stackoverflow page and shows my reputations badges. Can u suggest me

Comment: hope you can accept the answer no ?

Answer (score 40):

The official description is here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair

Answer (score 3):

html: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/flair

Comment: thank you for the link. But i didnt get where to copy and paste the code. Also, i want my staut the link you mention shows my wordpress.stackexchange.com profile. I want to link to http://stackoverflow.com/users/518371/batuli and not to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1794/batuli.

Comment: It really depends on your theme. Easiest would be to make a blank widget and paste the code.